# Mac app for testing websites in android emulator quickly

Tags: macos, applications, android

Hi I want to test my site locally on my Mac using the android device layout . The usual [android sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk) takes more time to load . Is there any app similar to opera mobile emulator which provides android device layout plus testing on local instance?
I want something like this

[image]

I think this is [samsung emulator](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk) for android, and for installing the samsung emulator on my local mac mini I didn't find any appropriate tutorial. Has anybody ever implemented this thing?

Comment: Welcome to the site Prateeak. Could you add a little bit about your requirements? Since we're a site about Apple hardware and software, just saying you want an app that runs on OS X would suffice and we can re-open this immediately. Depending on what exactly you seek, this might be better on Stack Overflow, but let's get details like OS and what link to "the usual android SDK" means specifically and take it from there...

Comment: @bmike : hi is this appropriate for the site now

Comment: Hi, I made a couple of minor edits for readability.  Does what I changes make sense?  You are essentially wanting to test websites using Android screen formats, on your Mac, right?

Comment: @stuffe good enough for me to vote to reopen

Answer (score 1):

You could try different ways of speeding up the Android emulator, such as running an x86 guest, and installing Intel HAXM.

If the graphics is slow, you can also try installing an "accelerated" emulator like GenyMotion, which seems to paravirtualize graphics APIs.

Comment: hi i think I figured the way it is easy to use samsung emulators